# How do I access the relationship name of a Core Data parent object?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a simple Core Data iPhone app where Parents have a one-to-many relationship with Children. In the first view, you are presented with a list of Parents; tapping on one provides the corresponding list of Children. In the Child view, I want the each cell to show the Child name, and then the Parent name as a subtitle. I have used the following command:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"Parent"] description];
```

But instead of getting the parent name, the subtitle displays something like:

```
<Parent: 0x4d5a520> (entity: Parent; id...
```

Obviously I'm printing out the actual relationship, rather than the object's name. How can I show the actual Parent name ("Mr Smith")?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to work it out! I'm gradually getting the hang of this programming thing... :-)

I'll leave the answer here in case someone else searches for it one day...

Instead of using a generic NSManagedObjectContext with KVC, I used my own subclass:

```
Child *child = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = [child.name description];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [child.parent.name description];
```

Comment: you could have used `cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[managedObject valueForKey:@"Parent"] valueForKey:@"name"] description];` you changed the keyPath of the object which gets the description message. That has nothing to do with a custom subclass.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt - you're absolutely right. I think that by changing it to a subclass and avoiding KVC it just made it easier to instinctively understand what I had to write (i.e. I hadn't even noticed on KVC that I wasn't accessing the actual name!). Thanks for telling me the syntax for the KVC way.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that `description` is a method of NSObject that returns a description useful for programmers. If you have an attribute called `description` then it will collide with the built-in description method. You may have been confused because when you call description on a NSString, you get the string but if you call any other class, you don't get the literal data e.g. When you call description on a managed object you get the object UUID, whether it is a fault or not, it's attributes and the objects it's related to. All that is useless for anything but debugging.

***Never use `description` as an attribute name and never use the return of `description` for anything the user ever sees.***

If you have a tableview of `Child` objects as described above then your fetched results controller will return a managed object configured to the `Child` entity. To access the name of the related `Parent` object you would use:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[childMo valueForKey:@"parent"] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Of course, if either the relationship or the parent.name attribute is optional, you should first check that either has a value before attempting to use the value.

Comment: It turns out that the main problem was that I stupidly forgot to ask for the "parent.name" - I just asked for "parent". So in fact, it worked even with "description", but I have followed your advice and removed it. Everything still works, and hopefully I will have avoided running into the problem you describe in future. Thanks!